# PHPUnit configure test

Tags: php, phpunit

```
class ControllerTest extends Zend_Test_PHPUnit_ControllerTestCase
{
    public $object;

    public function  setUp() {
        $this->bootstrap = array($this, 'boostrap');
        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function bootstrap(){
        $this->application = new Zend_Application(
                    APPLICATION_ENV,
                    APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini'
                );
        $this->application->bootstrap();

    }

    public function testIndexAction(){
        // body
    }

}
```

This is the class for the test. My question is how to implement the testIndexAction where the actual command on the command prompt is:

php zfrun.php -a ..index

Comment: Where does `zfrun.php` come from? Can you link to its source or post it if it's short? Zend's `ControllerTestCase` is designed to be given a route for dispatching, rendering the view, and making assertions about the resulting content.

Comment: zfrun.php comes from tests where it is also the root of the application. zfrun.php is like a bootstrap file. The actual bootstrap which is for the application Bootstrap.php also instantiates Zend_Console_Getopt which also defines the parameter to run the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing exactly what `zfrun.php` does, I can only guess, and it sounds like you need to ditch `ControllerTestCase`. `ControllerTestCase` is designed to mimic an HTTP request to send through the Zend dispatcher, but you don't need that.

Instead, you can try to mimic calling `zfrun.php` from the command line by setting up $argv as it would look and executing `zfrun.php` yourself:

```
function testIndexAction() {
    $argv = array(
            '-a',
            'module_name.controller_name.index',
        );
    require 'zfrun.php';
}
```

The problem is that this works for only one test, assuming `zfrun.php` defines classes or functions and cannot be required multiple times. Therefore, you'll need to do whatever `zfrun.php` does in a new test case base class without using `zfrun.php` itself. Essentially refactor its code into a reusable test helper method.

```
function executeControllerAction($module, $controller, $action) {
    ... whatever magic zfrun.php does ...
}
```

Comment: I just use manual testing. I actually needed to work on the setup of the PHPUnit test.

Comment: PHPUnit supports manual and automated testing as you've no doubt found. However, you must set up your environment to allow PHPUnit to access your classes and/or environment either route you take. Did this answer your question or help you solve the problem you're having?

Answer (score 0):

If this is the test for your home page, use

```
$this->dispatch('/');
```

If not, you'll have to give it the URL that will trigger the route to load this controller.